# How do I reference an object given a name in a constructor and I won't know what that name is?

Tags: java, constructor, getter-setter

I have a class called Chef, where there are three constructors.Like so:

```
public Chef(String chefName, double noodleStock) {
    this.chefName = chefName;
    this.noodleStock = noodleStock;
    this.bowlsCooked = 0;
}
public Chef(String chefName, double noodleStock, double vegStock) {
    this.chefName = chefName;
    this.noodleStock = noodleStock;
    this.vegStock = vegStock;
    this.bowlsCooked = 0;
}
public Chef(String chefName, double noodleStock, double vegStock,
    double porkStock) {
    this.chefName = chefName;
    this.noodleStock = noodleStock;
    this.vegStock = vegStock;
    this.porkStock = porkStock;
    this.bowlsCooked = 0;
}
```

In a method that stocks each chef, I will need to `setNoodleStock`, for example, by adding a value to their current stock.

How do I make sure I reference the correct chef? The only difference between each chef is going to be their name and the number of args in their constructor.

Comment: By the way, `this(chefName, noodleStock)` would save you a few lines of code here

Comment: If the name is different between each chef, why can't you reference them by name?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean - please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You know the correct Chef by keeping track of them.

```
Chef chef1 = new Chef(...);
Chef chef2 = new Chef(...);
Chef chef3 = new Chef(...);
```

It is irrelevant which constructor you use. Then to add stock to chef2, you use

```
chef2.addNoodleStock(amount);
```

Of course, you have to write the method addNoodleStock().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you define a `setNoodleStock()` method within your Chef class, i.e.

```
public class Chef {

   ... instance variables ...

   public Chef(String chefName, double noodleStock) {
       ...
   }

   public Chef(String chefName, double noodleStock, double vegStock) {
       ...
   }

   public Chef(String chefName, double noodleStock, double vegStock,
       double porkStock) {
       ...
   }

   public void setNoodleStock(double stock) {
      this.noodleStock = stock;
   }

}
```

Then later on, when you create `Chef` objects, whichever one you call `setNoodleStock()` on will have its stock set:

```
Chef chef1 = new Chef("First Chef", 2.0);

Chef chef2 = new Chef("Second Chef", 1.0);

chef1.setNoodleStock(4.0); // chef1 now has 4.0 noodles, chef2 still has 1.0

chef2.setNoodleStock(5.0); // chef1 has 4.0 noodles from above, chef2 now has 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make sure I reference the correct chef?

That would be something done where you actually have a reference to an instance of a `Chef`. Using different constructors doesn't change anything about a `Chef` instance.

If you need to reference a `Chef` by a `String name`, then you probably should using be using a `Map<String, Chef>`.

```
Chef joe = new Chef("joe", 0);
Map<String, Chef> chefs = new HashMap<String, Chef>();
chefs.put(joe.getName(), joe);
```

Somewhere else...

```
Chef joe = chefs.get("joe");
```

However, at that point, why not just use the `Chef joe` instance you already declared with a name?